# Exception running the WSO2 Identity Server STS Client

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I running the STS Client from sample located in

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Downloading+a+Sample

I am using 'sts-policy-ut.xml' as my policy (please refer to the code). I get the SAML2 tokens and I can validate too. When when I enable relyingPary flag in the 'client.properties' file, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
    at org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.handleSupportingTokens(BindingBuilder.java:392)
    at org.apache.rampart.builder.SymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingBuilder.java:499)
    at org.apache.rampart.builder.SymmetricBindingBuilder.build(SymmetricBindingBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:144)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.sts.Client.run(Client.java:239)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.samples.sts.Client.main(Client.java:95)
```

Please let me know how to fix it. I just using the recommended Maven way to build the project and running the supplied batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally upgraded the Axis 2 library including the Ramapart jars to the following :
i) Axis 2  - 1.7.7

ii) Rampart - 1.7.0

This solved the problem.  So this seems to be a bug with Axis 1.6.1 the version which the WSO2 uses for its examples.